# When I tried to load dataset for deep learning project, I got an error like below

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When executing this code:

```
caption_path = 'drive/MyDrive/projects/dl project/dataset/captions',
caption_path

captions = open(caption_path, 'rb').read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')
```

I got this error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 captions = open(caption_path, 'rb').read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please remember to format your answers to appear as code. The type error is due to the first line, you have a string in quotes, and then a comma then another variable (this makes a tuple). You need to change the first line to caption_path = "drive/MyDrive/projects/dl project/dataset/captions"

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
caption_path = 'drive/MyDrive/projects/dl project/dataset/captions', caption_path
```

do:

```
caption_path = 'drive/MyDrive/projects/dl project/dataset/captions'
```